# Manage multi site themes in magento 1.7

Tags: magento

I'm working in Magento 1.7, I've created multi site following this tutorial: http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/  . I'm using 02 themes with both a slider. In default store, theme works well, but in the second store, slider could not be displayed and also product's thumbnails. The 02 websites use the same root catalog (I don't know if it's recommanded). I don't understand why this problem appears. Could you please make help.

Thanks in advance

Best regards !

Comment: are you using different domains for the sites?

Answer (score 0):

For using different themes on multi website or multistore, you must prepare the template on the different folder on *root*/skin/frontend/*your-store-name*
After that, you can assign the skin on the backend system by accessing System > Configuration > Design(tab) and then change the web skin..